# Can I search by multiple fields using the Elastic Search Java API?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-java-api

**Example:**

```
|studentname | maths | computers |
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
|s1          |78     |90         |
==================================
|s2          |56     |75         |
==================================
|s3          |45     |50         |
==================================
```

The above table represents data that is present in Elasticsearch.

Consider that the user enters `60 and above` then Elasticsearch should be able to display only **s1**, because he is the only student who has scored more than 60 in both subjects.

How do I solve it using Java API?

NOTE: I was able to find out for individual subjects by:

```
    QueryBuilder query = QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
            .should(
                     QueryBuilders.rangeQuery(maths)
                    .from(50)
                    .to(100)
            )
```

Comment: Misunderstood you at first. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can have multiple `.should()` clauses in the the bool query. So in your case:

```
QueryBuilder query = QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
        .should(
                 QueryBuilders.rangeQuery(maths)
                .from(61)
                .to(100)
        )
        .should(
                 QueryBuilders.rangeQuery(computers)
                .from(61)
                .to(100)
        )
```

Note:

1. `RangeQueryBuilder` (returned from `QueryBuilders.rangeQuery()`) also has the method `#gte()`.
2. According to the docs: "In a boolean query with no must or filter clauses, one or more should clauses must match a document." So if you have have no `filter` or `must`, you might not get the desired behavior. The above answer assumes you are using some other clauses. **The point is you can combine clauses in the bool query.** With the Java API this just means using the clause repeatedly.
3. You might want to use filter instead of should. This will lead to faster execution and caching (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html)

Comment: Excellent :)! Note that if you don't need your results scored, you might want to use `filter` instead of `should`. This will lead to faster execution and caching (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html)

Comment: shouldn't this match student2(`s2`) as he have score in computers above 60.

Comment: @avr yes, I was thinking that it might. As it says in the docs: "In a boolean query with no must or filter clauses, one or more should clauses must match a document." But I left it up to the OP to test, and didn't assume he had no other clauses. I would use `filter` or `must` instead of `should`. I'll edit the answer, thank you.

Comment: Yes, we need to use either `filter`(I'd use filter as it is more performant than query)  or `must`.

Comment: Yeah, I updated the answer with all these notes. Thank you.